# htaccess does not require login when using POST

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, cgi, .htpasswd

I'm new to this so I'm hoping that this is just a issue of me not editing a config file properly.  I have a protected directory in my cgi-bin called /auth.  The auth directory has an .htaccess file in it.  First I made the htpasswd file as follows...

```
htpasswd -c /var/pass/.htpasswd username
```

Then I made the .htaccess file and put it in the auth directory.  The .htaccess file contains the following text...

```
AuthUserFile  /var/pass/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Protected Directory"
AuthType Basic

<Limit GET>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

I put a sample python script in /cgi-bin/auth called Test.py which contains the following text...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print 'Content-Type: text/html\n'

if form.has_key('text'): print form['text'].value
else: print 'No text entered'
```

When I go to localhost/cgi-bin/auth/Test.py I get the password prompt and I can login and see the 'No text entered' text so I know it works.

My problem is that there is no password prompt when I submit data to this protected file using the POST method.  For example, I made this file (called input.py) and put it in my /cgi-bin directory...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print 'Content-Type: text/html\n'

print '<form method="post" name="form_transfer" action="/cgi-bin/auth/outputTest.py">'
print '<input type="hidden" name="text" value="transferred"/>'
print '</form>'

print '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.form_transfer.submit(); return false">Click Me</a>'
```

I went to  localhost/cgi-bin/input.py and clicked on the Click Me link and my simple example (the "Test.py" script) does not ask me for a password.  It accepts the data and displays the text "transferred" immediately.  How do I stop it from doing this?  I want the user to have to login.

On a side note entering via GET actually DOES generate a password dialog (entered localhost/cgi-bin/auth/Test.py?text=printthis on my browser).  For some reason POST is not working.

EDIT.  Tyler Eaves solved this.  In the htaccess file, instead of `<LIMIT GET>` I typed `<LIMIT GET POST>` and it worked.

Comment: For _some_ reason? Don't you think it might have something to do with:  <Limit GET>. Why do you think that would apply to POST also?

Comment: Eek that is probably it.  Like I said, I'm new to this :/  I would accept your answer if I could...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  Solved it.  Thanks Tyler Eaves!

EDIT. Tyler Eaves solved this. In the htaccess file, instead of `<LIMIT GET>` I typed `<LIMIT GET POST>` and it worked.

Comment: Would be good if you could explain how you solved this for the benefit of others.

Comment: The solution is in Tyler Eaves comment.  Here is the explicit solution... Instead of <LIMIT GET> type <LIMIT GET POST>.  I will update my post to reflect this.

Comment: Ok...so can you put that in the answer?

Comment: Will do.  I didn't think it was necessary at the time because most viewers wouldn't have much of a problem figuring out the answer.  Also, I was hoping Tyler Eaves would eventually post his answer AS an answer so I could give him credit.  He never did though.

Comment: Much appreciate and helps make the internet a better place :)